# How do I approach this combinatorics problem about loan applications?

Tags: combinatorics

> When acting on loan applications it can be concluded, based on
>   historical records, that loan applicants having certain combinations
>   of features can be expected  to repay their loans and those who have
>   other combinations of features cannot. As their main features, suppose
>   that a bank uses:
>
> **Marital Status:** Married, Single (never married), Single (previously married).
>
> **Past Loan:** Previous default, No Previous default
>
> **Employment:** Employed,  Unemployed (within 1 year), Unemployed (more than 1 year).
>
> (a) How many different loan applications are possible when considering
>   these features?
>
> (b) How many manifestations of loan repayment/default are possible
>   when considering these features?

For part a, it seems plain to me that it's the product rule and is 3 * 2 * 3 = 18.  But I'm confused about the wording in (b) - what are manifestations , and how do I approach this part? I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: I think they mean that there are $2^{18}$ ways of drawing up the truth table of marital status / past loan / employment vs whether the load will be repaid or defaulted.

Comment: oops You  are right, Thank You Very Much. Hmm, I'll think more!

Comment: @David: Just $2\cdot 18=36$, two for each of the $18$ possible application types.

Comment: @Adel: If @David’s interpretation is right, you’re just adding a fourth category, Repay/Default, with two possible outcomes, so you can use the same kind of reasoning that you used to get $3\cdot 2\cdot 3$ in (a).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - either you've interpreted "manifestations" differently from me, or I haven't explained myself clearly. The question said that for some of the 18 possible combinations of features, the loan could be expected to be repaid; and for others, the loan could be expected to be defaulted. There are $2^{18}$ ways to choose which combinations of features resulted in an expectation of repayment. I guess you could argue that the wording of the question implies that at least one combination results in repayment, and at least one combination results in default, making the answer $2^{18}-2$.

Comment: @David: There are not $2^{18}$ ways to choose a combination of features: there are only $18$. You can have only one feature from each of the three types, Marital Status, Past Loan, and Employment. In other words, I’m basically accepting your interpretation of *manifestations* but arguing that you’re counting incorrectly.

Comment: @Brian, No I can count.  You and I are just understanding "manifestation" differently.  I took it to mean the whole table that the bank has, that lists the 18 combinations, and which of them leads to repayment, and which leads to default.  There are $2^{18}$ possible tables.  But the more I think about it, the more I think you're right about the meaning - here, "manifestation" probably just means one line of the table, that is, just one combination of marital status / loan history / employment.  I'm not disputing that there are 18 of these.

Comment: @David: Sorry $-$ I finally figured out what you’re doing. I should have realized earlier ($2^{18}$ is not $2^8). That possibility just never occurred to me.

Comment: @Brian - no worries.  I just hope that I haven't confused the original poster too much with my misinterpretation and our subsequent discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the reasonable interpretation is that for every one of the $18$ classes that a particular person can fall into, there are $2$ possibilities for the actual outcome (default or not default), for a total of $36$.

What I would add is that the usage of the word "manifestation" in the question has a definite French tinge. Although using "manifestation" (pronounce it in English) here is not quite idiomatic, if you pronounce it in French, it is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: Thank You Very Much! This makes a lot of sense  now!